# Can I have comments on some wordpress pages and not others?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site that I only want to allow people to post comments on certain pages.  For example, I want to allow comments on the first page, but then only again on the Gallery page.  I am using the toolbox theme and not sure how to make it happen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just googled and found this, does it help?

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-comments-function-on-certain-pages

Comment: scrap that, its for a certain theme.

Comment: The only other way i know of is, to create custom page templates and choose between them when it comes to publishing.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you were right.  There should be a checkbox at the bottom of each Edit page for "Allow Comments".  This is not theme specific.  You can disallow comments for each individual page.

Comment: Yeah i thought there was, i just then read something else that made me doubt myself. I dont have WP in front of me otherwise I would check.

Answer (score 1):

To remove comments from already published pages:
In WP Admin, Pages > Select all posts or just the ones you no longer want comments and click "Edit" under bulk actions and hit apply. Under "Comments" > Choose "do not allow". Click Update.
For posts, the same process starting at Posts >.

To remove comments from all new pages and posts from now on: `Settings >> Discussion >> uncheck "Allow people to post comments on new articles"`